# How to upload multiple files to a GCP bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have the following folder structure:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5Mv.png

```
metrics/
     a_metric/
         dags/files
     b_metric/
         dags/files
     c_metric/
         dags/files
```

[structure][1]

I already tried with locals, I think I need a map or something.
The result I want is maybe a map with value(local_path) key(remote_path)
Like:

```yaml
a_metric
   local_file_path : remote_file_path
```

```bash
locals {
  # Base variables 
  base_vars = yamldecode(file("base/vars.yaml"))

  
  #OK
  # Metrics subfolder names
  metrics = distinct([
    for dir_path in fileset("metrics/", "*/*/") :
    basename(dirname(dir_path))
  ])

  # Metrics configuration 
  metrics_config = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}", "vars.yaml") :
      merge(yamldecode(file("metrics/${subfolder}/${file}")), { subfolder = subfolder })
    ]
  ])


}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
  for_each = { for metric in local.metrics_config: metric.subfolder => metric }
  #for_each     = fileset("/metrics/${each.value.subfolder}/dags/", "*.py")

  name   = "dags/${each.value.subfolder}/"
  source = "metrics/${each.value.subfolder}/dags/"
  bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001" 
}
```

Plan Output:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_storage_bucket_object.default["a_metric"] will be created
  + resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      + bucket         = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
      + content_type   = (known after apply)
      + crc32c         = (known after apply)
      + detect_md5hash = "different hash"
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_name   = (known after apply)
      + md5hash        = (known after apply)
      + media_link     = (known after apply)
      + name           = "dags/a_metric/"
      + output_name    = (known after apply)
      + self_link      = (known after apply)
      + source         = "metrics/a_metric/dags/"
      + storage_class  = (known after apply)
    }

  # google_storage_bucket_object.default["b_metric"] will be created
  + resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      + bucket         = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
      + content_type   = (known after apply)
      + crc32c         = (known after apply)
      + detect_md5hash = "different hash"
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_name   = (known after apply)
      + md5hash        = (known after apply)
      + media_link     = (known after apply)
      + name           = "dags/b_metric/"
      + output_name    = (known after apply)
      + self_link      = (known after apply)
      + source         = "metrics/b_metric/dags/"
      + storage_class  = (known after apply)
    }

  # google_storage_bucket_object.default["c_metric"] will be created
  + resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      + bucket         = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
      + content_type   = (known after apply)
      + crc32c         = (known after apply)
      + detect_md5hash = "different hash"
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_name   = (known after apply)
      + md5hash        = (known after apply)
      + media_link     = (known after apply)
      + name           = "dags/c_metric/"
      + output_name    = (known after apply)
      + self_link      = (known after apply)
      + source         = "metrics/c_metric/dags/"
      + storage_class  = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

What I want is to upload the files or folders inside the tags folder.

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: Hi, @guillaumeblaquiere.

I edited the question comments.
As you can see the plan is only getting the directories. I want to iterate through files within the dags folders of each metric.

Answer (score 1):

It's working!!!
I have add this variables to locals metrics_dags_remote_path, metrics_dags_remote_path and path_map with zipmap.

My main.tf:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  project = local.base_vars.project
  region  = local.base_vars.region
}

locals {
  # Base variables 
  base_vars = yamldecode(file("base/vars.yaml"))

  
  #OK
  # Metrics subfolder names
  metrics = distinct([
    for dir_path in fileset("metrics/", "*/*/") :
    basename(dirname(dir_path))
  ])

  # Metrics configuration 
  metrics_config = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}", "vars.yaml") :
      merge(yamldecode(file("metrics/${subfolder}/${file}")), { subfolder = subfolder })
    ]
  ])

  #METRIC_DAGS_LOCAL_PATH OK
  metrics_dags_local_path = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") :
       join("/", ["metrics", subfolder ,"dags", file])
    ]
  ])

  #METRIC_DAGS_REMOTE_PATH OK
  metrics_dags_remote_path = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") :
       join("/", ["dags", subfolder, file])
    ]
  ])

  
  path_map = zipmap(local.metrics_dags_local_path, local.metrics_dags_remote_path)

}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
  for_each = local.path_map
          
  name  = each.value 
  source = each.key
  bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"

}

# OUTPUTS
output "base_vars" {
  value = local.base_vars
}

output "metrics" {
  value = local.metrics
}

output "metrics_config" {
  value = local.metrics_config
}

output "metrics_dags_local_path" {
  value = local.metrics_dags_local_path
}

output "metrics_dags_remote_path" {
  value = local.metrics_dags_remote_path
}


output "path_map" {
  value = local.path_map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a map of local_path to remote_path for each metric subfolder:--

```
locals {

  metric_paths = {
     for subfolder in local.metrics :
    subfolder => {
      local_path = "metrics/${subfolder}/dags"
      remote_path = "dags/${subfolder}/"
    }}
   }
```

This will create a map where the key is the metric subfolder name, and the value is another map containing the local_path and remote_path.

Next, you can iterate over the metric_paths map to create a bucket object for each metric subfolder, and upload the contents of the local_path to the remote_path:--

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      for_each = local.metric_paths

      name   = each.value.remote_path
      source = each.value.local_path
      bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
    }
```

This will create a bucket object for each metric subfolder, and upload the contents of the dags folder in each metric subfolder to their respective bucket objects.

Modified

This should create a nested map structure where the top-level keys are the subfolder names and the inner keys are the file names.

By using each.key and each.value.file, you can access the subfolder and file names from the map.

```
locals = {
  metrics_paths = {
    for subfolder in local.metrics : subfolder => {
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") : file => {
        local_path = "metrics/${subfolder}/dags/${file}"
        remote_path = "dags/${subfolder}/${file}"
      }
    }
  }
}
 
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
  for_each = local.metrics_paths

  bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
  name   = "dags/${each.key}/${each.value.file}"
  source = each.value.local_path
}
```

Comment: With the above code I can't get the files inside the local folders.


`Terraform will perform the following actions:
  # google_storage_bucket_object.default["a_metric"] will be created
  + resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      + bucket         = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
      + name           = "dags/a_metric/"
      + source         = "metrics/a_metric/dags"
    }`

Comment: Something like this:

`
locals = { 
    
    
    metrics_paths = { 
    for subfolder in local.metrics : { 
        for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") : 
        subfolder => { local_path = "metrics/${subfolder}/dags/${file}"  remote_path = "dags/${subfolder}/${file}" }
      }
    }
    
}`

Comment: ``` terraform
  metrics_paths = [ 
    for subfolder in local.metrics : 
{      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") : 
        subfolder => { 
          local_path = "metrics/${subfolder}/dags/${file}"
          remote_path = "dags/${subfolder}/${file}"
          }...}
    
  ]

```

Comment: The code above is return the Error:

    `on main.tf line 47, in resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default":
│   47:       for_each = local.metrics_paths
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.metrics_paths is tuple with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.`

Comment: Try using the new one