# Terraform - Upload multiples files GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

The objective is to take only the files or folders from the dags folder for each metric and transfer them to a bucket, which needs to have this structure bucket/dags/metric_name/files.

I have the following folder structure: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5Mv.png

```
metrics/
     a_metric/dags/
                  shared/files
                  files
     b_metric/dags/
                  shared/files
                  files
     c_metric/dags/
                  shared/files
                  files

Bukcet:
dags/
  a_metric/filesORFolders_inside_dags_folder
  b_metric/filesORFolders_inside_dags_folder
  c_metric/filesORFolders_inside_dags_folder
```

My main.tf:

```
  project = local.base_vars.project
  region  = local.base_vars.region
}

locals {
  # Base variables 
  base_vars = yamldecode(file("base/vars.yaml"))

  
  #OK
  # Metrics subfolder names
  metrics = distinct([
    for dir_path in fileset("metrics/", "*/*/") :
    basename(dirname(dir_path))
  ])

  # Metrics configuration 
  metrics_config = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}", "vars.yaml") :
      merge(yamldecode(file("metrics/${subfolder}/${file}")), { subfolder = subfolder })
    ]
  ])



   metrics_paths = [ 
     for subfolder in local.metrics : 
 {      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") : 
         subfolder => { 
           local_path = "metrics/${subfolder}/dags/${file}"
           remote_path = "dags/${subfolder}/${file}"
           }...}
   
  ]

 

}



resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
      for_each = local.metrics_paths
      
      name   = each.value.remote_path
      source = each.value.local_path
      bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
    }




# OUTPUTS
output "base_vars" {
  value = local.base_vars
}

output "metrics" {
  value = local.metrics
}

output "metrics_paths" {
  value = local.metrics_paths
}
output "metrics_config" {
  value = local.metrics_config
}
```

It is returning the following error.

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 55, in resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default":
│   55:       for_each = local.metrics_paths
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.metrics_paths is tuple with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

Comment: Seems like the error couldn't be more obvious, for_each doesn't work on a tuple, so don't give it a tuple. You might also be able to use count instead of for_each if you don't want to rewrite that list/tuple construction, but frankly it's unreadable as far as I'm concerned, so I'd construct that list in another way, probably not in HCL.

Comment: @somethingsomething
How do I transform or create a map?

Comment: Are you reposting the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826422/how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-a-gcp-bucket

Comment: It's working!!! I have add this variables to locals metrics_dags_remote_path, metrics_dags_remote_path and path_map with zipmap.

Answer (score 1):

It's working!!!
I have add this variables to locals metrics_dags_remote_path, metrics_dags_remote_path and path_map with zipmap.

```
  #METRIC_DAGS_LOCAL_PATH OK
  metrics_dags_local_path = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") :
       join("/", ["metrics", subfolder ,"dags", file])
    ]
  ])

  #METRIC_DAGS_REMOTE_PATH OK
  metrics_dags_remote_path = flatten([
    for subfolder in local.metrics :
    [
      for file in fileset("metrics/${subfolder}/dags", "**") :
       join("/", ["dags", subfolder, file])
    ]
  ])

  
  path_map = zipmap(local.metrics_dags_local_path, local.metrics_dags_remote_path)

}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "default" {
  for_each = local.path_map
          
  name  = each.value 
  source = each.key
  bucket = "bucket_test_dags_terraform_001"
```